# Razor. ASP.NET MVC 3. Dynamically create pages/content

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

*The problem for me is to understand how to render the dynamically created pages with a uniq URL's when the page don't have a Controller/View to map to.*

I am building a CMS-system In ASP.NET MVC 3 3 with Razor. In a database I store the page/site structure and content.

I guess i need to have some render action in a controller that create a custom view with the content from database? and what about the URL's?

Answer (score 3):

I'd make a separate folder (like "DynamicContent" or something) to keep those dynamic pages in and add corresponding `IgnoreRoute` call to RegisterRoutes method in Global.asax.cs, like this:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("DynamicContent/{*pathInfo}");

    ...
}
```

After that users will be able to access those pages using URLs like

http://%your_site%/DynamicContent/%path_to_specific_file%

**UPDATE**

If you don't want to lay files on server HDD then you may really create a special controller for those files. Route for this should look this:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    ...

    routes.MapRoute(
        "DynamicRoute", // Route name
        "Dynamic/{*pathInfo}", // URL with parameters
        new { controller = "Dynamic", action = "Index"} // Parameter defaults
    );

}
```

Your DynamicController.cs should look like this:

```
public class DynamicController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index(string pathInfo)
    {
        // use pathInfo value to get content from DB
        ...
        // then 
        return new ContentResult { Content = "%HTML/JS/Anything content from database as string here%", ContentType = "%Content type either from database or inferred from file extension%"}
        // or (for images, document files etc.)
        return new FileContentResult(%file content from DB as byte[]%, "%filename to show to client user%");
    }
}
```

Note that asterisk (*) before pathInfo will make this route grab entire URL part after `Dynamic` - so if you have entered http://%your_site%/Dynamic/path/to/file/something.html then an entire string `path/to/file/something.html` will be passed in parameter `pathInfo` to DynamicController/Index method.

Comment: Thanks for answer, but if i what the URL's to mirror the dynamically created structure in the database. ex: www.mysite.com/about/contact
then the about and contact is just a page-structure in the database.

I hope you understand what i mean ? :)

Comment: @Mickjohansson: Modified my answer accordingly, hope it helps.